# How to get XML out of HTTP Request in ASP

Tags: android, xml, http, asp-classic

I'm trying to post an XML page in Android with HTTP POST to an ASP-page. My problem now is that I'm not really a ASP-programmer, but I need this page in ASP. Can someone help me on track to get the XML out of the HTTP Post and into my ASP, so I can save the XML-file on my server? Thank you very much.

In Android, I'm going to put my XML in a StringBuilder, following this example.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.append("<ArrayOfString>");
sb.append("<string>").sb.append("the_command").sb.append("</string>");
sb.append("</ArrayOfString>");

StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(sb.toString(), "UTF-8");
httppost.setEntity(entity);  
httppost.addHeader("Accept", "application/xml");
httppost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

In my ASP-page looks like this for the moment

```vb
<%
strFilenaam = "d:\myhrm\android\xml\" & day(now) & month(now) & year(now) & hour(now) & minute(now) & second(now)
set oFs = server.createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

blnOk = oFs.fileExists(strFilenaam & intTeller & "httppost.xml")
Do While blnOk = True
intTeller = intTeller + 1
blnOk = oFs.fileExists(strFilenaam & intTeller & "httppost.xml")
Loop
set oTextFile = oFs.OpenTextFile(strFilenaam & intTeller & "httppost.xml", 2, True)

oTextFile.Write "Test"
oTextFile.Close
set oTextFile = nothing
set oFS = nothing

Response.Write("OK")
%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setEntity sets your request body in plain text (in this case the XML data). Usually you need key-value pairs that you can read via the Request.Form collection. You might want to try the Request.BinaryRead method in this case.